# Keycloak Impersonate

Tags: java, session, cookies, keycloak, impersonation

I need to provide the **impersonate** functionality outside of Keycloak Admin Console, the very similiar to Impersonate button. 
What I am doing is calling Keycloak REST API for

1. obtaining the access_token, (auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token)
2. which is then parsed into another call to impersonate user admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/impersonation .

The second call is returning redirect link with boolean and in the headers there are, besides others, KEYCLOAK_SESSION and KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY cookies.

I need to somehow logout the user from the application, set those cookies in the  browser, do the redirect to login page and be logged in as the another user. I think its common situation and Keycloak has its miracle Impersonate button which does the same, but I need to have it outside of Admin Console. Could somebody assist with hep with this issue? Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just implemented this feature for our KC, the approach we took was using REST api's. The "Super User" needs to be logged in (valid KC session). Then they can initiate an impersonation session, we chose to use the username to find the impersonatee. Once you validate the person exist within the KC realm you can create a `UserSessionModel` for that person. Then create a login cookie, I learned that KC `AuthenticationManager` has a near little method that creates a login cookie and appends it to the response headers (really cool). Then I stored my credentials (Super User) inside a cookie and returned the response with those cookies appended. The return REST method is a very similar process, the parameters it takes are different because we need to pass the cookies back and grab the super user id and his session id. Once you have those you just repeat the first method (find user, find session instead of creating a new unless old session timed out), redirect back to origin. Oh also don't forget to end the impersonation session.

```
personYouImpersonatedSessionId = session.sessions().getUserSession(RealmModel,AuthSessionId)
if(!personYouImpersonatedSessionId) {
      session.sessions().removeUserSession(RealmModel,personYouImpersonatedSessionId)
}
```

I forgot to do that during testing and was running into some issues. I know the post is old but there are people still looking for this type of information :D

I hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

This is too late to respond but it might help if someone is still looking for an easy solution. We encountered the same use-case where we wanted to provide impersonation outside the Keycloak (in OIDC client).
To achieve this we used Keycloak impersonation REST API.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource.

Make sure to provide impersonation permission to the Keycloak logged-in user before calling this API. Read more info on below link.
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/token-exchange/token-exchange.adoc#impersonation

This API sends complete impersonated user details in the response including access tokens, session cookies, and CORS headers. like the below image.
[image]

We leveraged CORS header allow-credentials and sent an ajax request  to Keycloak with
"withCredentials: true". This option directed the browser to replace all the cookies with the new ones.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this answer. Its really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I have been digging in order to find a solution for this one as well. I finally found this article: https://blog.softwaremill.com/who-am-i-keycloak-impersonation-api-bfe7acaf051a.

In summary in my case I have done:

1. Create service-client (Direct Access Grants Enabled; Service Accounts Enabled) in Keycloak: add impersonate role to the client;
2. Call REST API to generate an intermediate token;

```
# Getting intermediate token
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MY_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=vanilla' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=c41da386-b4fc-4202-b799-53196284e44f' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

3. Call REST API to exchange the token for impersonated access token;

```
Impersonated user Access-Token
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MY_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=vanilla' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=c41da386-b4fc-4202-b799-53196284e44f' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange' \
--data-urlencode 'subject_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP_2> \
--data-urlencode 'requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_subject=34307875-39a6-4828-8cf0-f59f403bd51f'
```

4. Use the token to access the desired Resource; e.g.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8090/todos' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP_3>'
```

Note: Keycloak Server must be enabled for exchange tokens: [Keycloak impersonation API not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496638/keycloak-impersonation-api-not-implemented)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. Anyone need a Java implementation ready, here is my post: https://datmt.com/backend/java/get-keycloak-access-token-without-password/